# convert all office documents in sharepoint to use 2010 format

Tags: office-web-apps, document-converter, office

So recently we migrated to SharePoint 2010, as well as migrated to Office 2010 from using Office 03/07 mixed environments. I would like to find a way to convert all the documents in a document library, site collection, and/or web application to convert to the office 2010 version .xlsx, .docx, .pptx, etc. for use in Office Web Apps..

Is there an easy way to do this without opening a file one by one and converting and saving?

Comment: Just so you are aware, doing this will break all bookmarks and links that people may have to those documents

Comment: I'm well aware. Thanks. I think the Office Web Apps feature would be a much better utilization of document collaboration in the document library than a hardlink in Excel/Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the [Office File Converter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179019.aspx) but it sounds very close to what you are looking for...